# How to implement a link constraint between the weights/bias of a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm new to the forum, and although I've tried my best, I hope not to write a duplicate post.

Here's the background:
I'm trying to build a neural network from scratch where certain weights are related to each other. For example, I have 2 sigmoid cells of weight and bias (w1, b1) and (w2,b2). I want these two sigmoids to intersect at 0.5 on the ordinate.
After calculation, I obtain the following constraints on the variables:
w_1 * b_2 - w_2 * b_1 =0
However, I don't know how to handle this constraint and integrate it into my neural network.

I have several ideas, but they all seem to have drawbacks:

1. Add a constraint directly to the loss function? I read about this in an article, but I don't understand how an equality constraint can be found in the loss function. We're not trying to "minimize" this constraint, but to make it true all the time.
2. Use the projected gradient method, but my constraint space is variable and depends on the weights/bias themselves?
3. Add a constraint layer? But where do I place it? How can I be sure that I'm still dealing with the same problem?

Have you seen anywhere a method or type of algorithm that uses this kind of constraint?

Thanks a lot!